# Message box NOT showing up using MessageBoxButton.Show(string, string, button)

Tags: c#, vba, messagebox

I have a reference set up already for `System.Windows.Form` and I'm not really sure what I'm missing. All I need is for a message box to show up when I change views on the info path form which shows Ok/Cancel and the two strings?

```
using Microsoft.Office.InfoPath;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;


namespace Form1
{
    public sealed class MessageBox
    {
     static public void Show(string input1, string input2, MessageBoxButtons button) { }
    } 

   public partial class FormCode
   {



          public void InternalStartup()
          {}

          public void FormEvents_ViewSwitched(object sender,   ViewSwitchedEventArgs e)
              {
                string string1 = "Error";
                string string2 = "Empty field found on form";
                MessageBoxButtons button = MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel;
                MessageBox.Show(string1, string2, button);
              }
      }
```

}

Comment: Why did you write your own `MessageBox.Show` method?  There's nothing in it that will "show" the `MessageBox`.

Comment: remove your `MessageBox` class.  I'm guessing you clicked the auto-generate class and method option before you added a reference to `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: This built-in [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox(v=vs.110).aspx) didn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your own *MessageBox* class.

```
public sealed class MessageBox
{
    static public void Show(string input1, string input2, MessageBoxButtons button) { }
}
```

Its *Show* method does not contain any implementation and does not let you call the [MessageBox.Show](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z(v=vs.110).aspx) method implemented in WinForms.

Comment: Is there a way for me to see how the MessageBox.Show method has been implemented in WinForms?

Comment: @ohmygrabovski - You can use a decompiler. But why do you need that?

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed out the solution, implement the show method. You might also consider having a special class of wrappers for showing a dialog to the user something like the following which has hard-coded buttons and the buttons are setup so the no or cancel button is the default. Lastly when using them we simply ask for true or false rather than a dialog result which at least for me is cleaner code.

Not so crazy for the function name QuestionOkayCancel but the naming here is for anyone reading to get the idea and many would surely change the function name is my guess.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Windowspplication1_cs
{
    public static class SpecialMyDialogs
    {
        public static bool Question(string Text)
        {
            return (MessageBox.Show(Text, "Question", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes);
        }
        public static bool Question(string Text, string Title)
        {
            return (MessageBox.Show(Text, Title, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes);
        }
        public static bool QuestionOkayCancel(string Text)
        {
            return (MessageBox.Show(Text, "Question", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes);
        }
        public static bool QuestionOkayCancel(string Text, string Title)
        {
            return (MessageBox.Show(Text, Title, MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == DialogResult.Yes);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I modified my code however, the box still is not showing up. I'm not sure if my return type is correct?

Comment: Best to show the new code by revising your question and indicate that you have modified it.